# FreeFlyCamera in Unity with new Input System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I switched to the new Input System and started rewriting scripts for it, now I have rewritten the camera control, but I have a problem, now I can't take into account the rotation of the camera when flying freely with the motion button pressed.
When, for example, I move in the direction where the camera is looking (straight), after which I turn the camera to the side and do not release the movement button, the movement continues in the original direction, although I expect that I will move in the direction where I turned the camera

```
using Drone;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class FreeFlyCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float _currentIncrease = 1;
    private float _currentIncreaseMem;
    private float _currentSpeed;
    private Vector3 _deltaPosition;

    private Vector3 _initPosition;
    private Vector3 _initRotation;

    private CursorLockMode _wantedMode;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        InputManager.Instance.SetCursorEvent += CursorState;
        InputManager.Instance.CameraBoostEvent += CameraBoost;
        InputManager.Instance.CameraMoveEvent += CameraMove;
        InputManager.Instance.CameraZoomEvent += CameraZoom;
        InputManager.Instance.CameraChangeHeightEvent += CameraChangeHeight;
        InputManager.Instance.LockCursorEvent += LockCursor;
    }

    private void CameraMove(Vector2 value)
    {
        SetDefaultParameters();
        
        var moveDirection = new Vector3(value.x, 0f, value.y);
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);

        _deltaPosition += moveDirection;
        
        CameraMove();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        InputManager.Instance.SetCursorEvent -= CursorState;
        InputManager.Instance.CameraBoostEvent -= CameraBoost;
        InputManager.Instance.CameraMoveEvent -= CameraMove;
        InputManager.Instance.CameraZoomEvent -= CameraZoom;
        InputManager.Instance.CameraChangeHeightEvent -= CameraChangeHeight;
        InputManager.Instance.LockCursorEvent -= LockCursor;
    }

    private void LockCursor()
    {
        _wantedMode = _wantedMode == CursorLockMode.Locked ? CursorLockMode.None : CursorLockMode.Locked;
        InputManager.Instance.TurnCameraActionMap();
    }

    private void CameraChangeHeight(float value)
    {
        SetDefaultParameters();
        
        var heightDirection = new Vector3(0f, value, 0f);
        heightDirection = transform.TransformDirection(heightDirection);

        _deltaPosition += heightDirection;
        
        CameraMove();
    }

    private void CameraZoom(float value)
    {
        SetDefaultParameters();

        _deltaPosition += transform.forward * value * 10;
        
        CameraMove();
    }

    private void SetDefaultParameters()
    {
        _deltaPosition = Vector3.zero;
        _currentSpeed = movementSpeed;
    }

    private void CameraMove()
    {
        if (enableMovement)
        {
            // Calc acceleration
            CalculateCurrentIncrease(_deltaPosition != Vector3.zero);

            transform.position += _deltaPosition * _currentSpeed * _currentIncrease;
        }
    }

    private void CameraBoost()
    {
        _currentSpeed = boostedSpeed;
    }

    private void CursorState()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = _wantedMode = CursorLockMode.None;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!active)
            return;

        SetCursorState();

        if (Cursor.visible)
            return;

        // Translation
        // if (enableTranslation)
            // transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Mouse.current.scroll.y.ReadValue() * Time.deltaTime * translationSpeed);
            
        CameraMove();
            
        // Rotation
        if (enableRotation)
        {
            // Pitch
            transform.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(
                -Mouse.current.delta.y.ReadValue() * mouseSense * Time.smoothDeltaTime,
                Vector3.right
            );
            

            // Paw
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(
                transform.eulerAngles.x,
                transform.eulerAngles.y + Mouse.current.delta.x.ReadValue() * mouseSense  * Time.smoothDeltaTime,
                transform.eulerAngles.z
            );
        }
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        if (boostedSpeed < movementSpeed)
            boostedSpeed = movementSpeed;
    }
#endif


    // Apply requested cursor state
    private void SetCursorState()
    {
        // Apply cursor state
        Cursor.lockState = _wantedMode;
        // Hide cursor when locking
        Cursor.visible = CursorLockMode.Locked != _wantedMode;
    }

    private void CalculateCurrentIncrease(bool moving)
    {
        _currentIncrease = Time.deltaTime;

        if (!enableSpeedAcceleration || (enableSpeedAcceleration && !moving))
        {
            _currentIncreaseMem = 0;
            return;
        }

        _currentIncreaseMem += Time.deltaTime * (speedAccelerationFactor - 1);
        _currentIncrease = Time.deltaTime + Mathf.Pow(_currentIncreaseMem, 3) * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    #region UI

    [Space] [SerializeField] [Tooltip("The script is currently active")]
    private bool active = true;

    [Space] [SerializeField] [Tooltip("Camera rotation by mouse movement is active")]
    private bool enableRotation = true;

    [SerializeField] [Tooltip("Sensitivity of mouse rotation")]
    private float mouseSense = 1.8f;

    [Space] [SerializeField] [Tooltip("Camera zooming in/out by 'Mouse Scroll Wheel' is active")]
    private bool enableTranslation = true;

    [SerializeField] [Tooltip("Velocity of camera zooming in/out")]
    private float translationSpeed = 55f;

    [Space] [SerializeField] [Tooltip("Camera movement by 'W','A','S','D','Q','E' keys is active")]
    private bool enableMovement = true;

    [SerializeField] [Tooltip("Camera movement speed")]
    private float movementSpeed = 10f;

    [SerializeField] [Tooltip("Speed of the quick camera movement when holding the 'Left Shift' key")]
    private float boostedSpeed = 50f;

    [Space] [SerializeField] [Tooltip("Acceleration at camera movement is active")]
    private bool enableSpeedAcceleration = true;

    [SerializeField] [Tooltip("Rate which is applied during camera movement")]
    private float speedAccelerationFactor = 1.5f;

    #endregion UI
}
```

Comment: why are you calling the `CameraMove` from both, the `CameraMove(Vector2)` callback and also `Update`? I would probably wait with doing the world to local space conversion until within `CameraMove` and do e.g. `transform.position += transform.rotation * _deltaPosition * _currentSpeed * _currentIncrease;` or even go through `localPosition`